# How to use vector of strings in measure.vars in melt in R?

Tags: r, melt, measure

I have a data.csv file as:

```
BBBB,  B, OOB 

CCCC,  C, OOC

DDDD,  D, OOD

EEEE,  E, OOE
```

I obtained the 2nd column as:

```
df1 <- read.csv(data, header=FALSE,strip.white=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[2].
```

The question is how can I use the df1 as c("B", "C", "D", "E)" in the melt function to use the df1 as measure.vars for a different set of data (data2 for example which has headers as B,C,D,E).

```
B,C,D,E

9.43,9.49,9.61,9.04


7.01,3.43,3.63,3.55

10.35,9.05,9.49,8.45

4.83,1.89,1.79,1.94

10.3,10.39,9.67,8.95
```

I wanted to use as:

```
df2 = data.frame(melt(data2, measure.vars=df1, variable.name=xxxx, value.name="yyyy"), m="zzzz")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we use `[` without any `,`, then it would be still a `data.frame` with a single column (assuming the original dataset is `data.frame`.  Better option is `[[` to extract as a vector and the `measure` argument expects a `vector`.  It is also better to wrap with `unique` (in case there are duplicates)

```
v1 <- unique(read.csv('file.csv', header=FALSE,strip.white=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[[2]])
```

Now, we use that in `measure`

```
library(reshape2)
df2 <- data.frame(melt(data2, measure.vars=v1, variable.name='xxxx', 
         value.name="yyyy"), m="zzzz")
```